# Issues with generating body normal map

Tags: normal-map

first post!

I'm a student who is currently taking a 3D Modeling and Animation class for Blender, and for our final project we're doing the entire workflow for a character model (sculpting, retopo, texturing, weight paint, animation, etc). I've been working on my normal maps for the three objects in the mesh, but I've had an issue with the last mesh in particular.

For reference, we've been using the "Blender 2.91 Essential Training" tutorial series on LinkedinLearning for pretty much everything, including the map baking workflow.

After following the tutorials to the letter (and in previous attempts, I've experimented with the extrusion and max ray distance to see if it just wasn't baking enough of the depth), my normal map for the body is mostly blank with some areas of depth, but not really.

[image: Normal Map Result]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/4l7kcttnmkx81.png?width=2048&format=png&auto=webp&s=8f508f833985961d91f5b2f442cb6d5948b2486d))</sub>

Here are just some screenshots of my settings: I am using Blender 2.9.7 on Windows 10. If there's any other specs required, please let me know!

**.Blend file with textures can be found [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZyT2WNiHh71ex6HLkh9Yf6cqGSO9R-fD/view?usp=sharing)**

[image: Model Compared to Normal Map]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/mcuyd8uznkx81.png?width=1917&format=png&auto=webp&s=dc74c48205f59d8e7fe8100ba9fb151bcab06131))</sub>

[image: Bake Settings]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/qjzbliv3okx81.png?width=357&format=png&auto=webp&s=15d279ad7a25724572f0382588bf42b4d2322877))</sub>

(I'm also using Cycles; Supported; GPU Compute; Open Shading Language)

[image: Lowpoly Material Shading]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/d1vfoqf9okx81.png?width=1237&format=png&auto=webp&s=d5d7ef62507331d9b793b92d71489f2be30b8d2f))</sub>

[image: Highpoly Material Shading]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/uvt0sk6hokx81.png?width=594&format=png&auto=webp&s=5af3d1101db4d9f9bf813fdf3fbe0e9d77358fa9))</sub>

[image: UV Map]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/nl7hcj2kokx81.png?width=710&format=png&auto=webp&s=141212e8087017c722ae5793ce4c25a7fe7a8b15))</sub>

I'm hoping it's not a stupid solution, since my other normal maps have worked fine, but I appreciate any help! Thank y'all again!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! I tried to bake your body and here is the result I got:
[image]
The only thing that I changed is that I deleted all the empty material slots for the low poly body.
And I set the render sample value to 1 but that's just for the faster baking.

If you want to get rid of those yellowish-greenish parts from your bake you can start playing with the Extrusion and MRD values, but you can also separate your mesh parts apart from each other, like so:

[image]

If you do this you must move also the high poly version.